# Quick access to program shortcut

Tags: windows-8-preview

I need to edit a text file on my computer that requires admin access (hosts).  I used to do this by hitting <kbd>WIN</kbd> and typing "Note".  The shortcut for Notepad would show up, and I could right-click and choose **Run as Administrator**.

How do I accomplish the same thing in Windows 8?  Notepad isn't something I see pinned to my start menu, and I don't really want to clutter up my menu with something I may use infrequently.

I want very quick access to my programs by typing a few letters in the name.  If I use <kbd>WIN</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, I have to know exactly the name of the executable.  I want to just type Glob and see options for Sonic Global VPN.  And I want to be able to execute that found executable as an admin if I need to.  Windows Vista & Windows 7 are excellent at this.  Surely this functionality has not been deprecated in Windows 8...

Comment: According to your question if you really have administrative privilages then you can directly edit the **hosts** file. You can go to %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\ and edit the hosts file.

Comment: You could make notepad always open as an Administrator, by checking run as Admin in Compatibility settings.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the metro desktop.  Start typing note...  You will see notepad as one of the apps. When you right click on the notepad icon you will see options on the bottom of the screen.  One of the options is to run-as-administrator...

Just to clarify: when you right click on the metro desktop do it against the background not against any of the icons or apps.